# Allauth package : provider_login_url redirect to /accounts/github/login/ before https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize

Tags: django-allauth

I tried to do this tutoriel for Allauth. (https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-allauth-tutorial).

Allauth work, but i don't understand why there is a intermediate page between signin link and https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize.

Given that i click on signin, i am redirect to /accounts/github/login/ then i must be click on button to redirect to https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize.

Thanks for your help.

[First screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HxgR.png) [Second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMi8b.png) [Third screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl2sJ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same question, I found my answer. It is necessary to add the following to `settings.py`:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True
```